# Unexpected (not working?) css3 transition with opacity and z-index on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, z-index, opacity

I'm trying to fade an object with css3.

So I use transition to animate the object state from opacity 1 to opacity 0 and set the z-index to -1 at the end of the transition to be able to act on the content bellow (select a text for instance).

That works on Chrome but not on Firefox, here is the simple fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8qtg5wuj/5/

### CSS:

```
.wrapper {border:2px solid #f00;width:200px;height:200px;position:relative;}

.inner:before
{content:'';
background:#ccc;
width:105%;
height:105%;
position:absolute;
top:-2.5%;
left:-2.5%;
z-index:1;
opacity:1;
transition:z-index 0, opacity 1.2s;}

.wrapper:hover .inner:before
{transition:z-index 0 1.2s, opacity 1.2s;
opacity:0;
z-index:-1;}
```

Has anyone ever encountered that problem, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox requires the units for the time values, even zero (`0s`, not just `0`). It's correct according to the [CSS Units and Values spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#time) because all dimensions (except lengths, for historical reasons) need to have the units specified even for zero values.

Comment: Awesome that was fast and efficient. How could I miss that!